# SharePoint 2013 Blog Template Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, word

I have created a custom template in Word 2013 and uploaded it to a document library in SharePoint 2013. It is a blog template, I have created a link that when you click it, it is suppose to open up a new document of that template I created. Instead it is opening up the actual template word document. This is a problem because I want them to be able to click the link and it create a new document with the template. Can anyone help me with this problem?